# How can I find the surface area of the circle m only with the given information?

Tags: circles, area

I have this question in my textbook: AB is a chord in the circle M, MC is perpendicular to AB, D is the midpoint of MA, CD = 3 cm, then the surface area of the circle M = how many squared centimeters?
I tried to solve it by getting the radius of the circle, but I can't get it from the provided information. From the model answers, it seems that the right radius length should be 6, double the length of CD, but I still can't prove it should be so from the question. Could you please help me?
[image: image of the circle]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you, I edited it. Please tell me if there is anything else I should do.

Comment: What makes you assume that MD=DA≠CD?

Comment: @piita I think there is no real evidence that this is the case, even though it seems like they are equal.

Comment: CDA is always iso, as is CMD. CD splits the right triangle into two isosceles.

Comment: Draw a rectangle with AC and CM as two of the sides. Then AM is one diagonal of the rectangle., and D the centre of the rectangle. The two diagonals of any rectangle have the same length and cut each other in half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:** The median of a triangle to a side is half of the side in length *if and only if* the triangle is a right-angled triangle and the side is the hypotenuse. 
**Proof:** We will first prove that the median to the hypotenuse is half of it. Consider a right-angled $\triangle ABC$ where $AC$ is the hypotenuse and $BD$ is the median drawn on it. Construct a line passing from $D$ parallel to $BC$ which cuts $AB$ at $E$.

[image]

$$\angle AED = \angle ABC = 90^\circ = \angle BED \tag{Corresponding angles}\label{1}$$
$$AD = CD \tag{$BD$ is median}\label{2}$$
$$AE = BE \tag{Converse of Mid-Point Theorem}\label{3}$$
Consider $\triangle BED$ and $\triangle AED$:
$$AE = BE \tag{shown above}\label{4}$$
$$\angle AED = \angle BED \tag{shown above}\label{5}$$
$$ED = ED \tag{Common}\label{6}$$
Thus, by $SAS$ rule of congruency, we get $\triangle BED \cong \triangle AED$ and hence $BD = AD$. But we also have $AD = CD$, hence,
$$\boxed{BD = AD = CD = \frac 12 AC}$$

Now, we will show that if in a triangle, the median drawn to a side is equal to half of it in length, the triangle is a right-angled triangle, and the angle opposite to the longest side is $90^\circ$ (or the side is the hypotenuse). Consider $\triangle ABC$, where $BD$ is a median drawn to $AC$ which is half in length of $AC$.

[image]

$$AD = CD = \frac 12 AC\tag{$BD$ is median}\label{7}$$
$$\color{blue}{BD} = \frac 12 AC = \color{blue}{AD} = \color{blue}{CD} \tag{Given $BD = 0.5 AC$}\label{8}$$
So, we can draw a circle centred at $D$ passing through $A,B,C$.

[image]

Clearly, $AC$ is the diameter, and by Thales's Theorem$^{[*]}$,
$$\boxed{\angle ABC = 90^\circ \iff \triangle ABC \text{ is right-angled, and hypotenuse is $AC$}}$$
QED.

---

Using this theorem, you can easily show that the radius of the circle in question is $6$ cm.

---

$^{[*]}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Draw a line from $D$ to some point $D'$ on $CA$ such that the line connecting $D$ to $D'$ is perpendicular to $CA$. Using the concept of Similar Triangles, you should be able to show that the triangles $DCD'$ and $DAD'$ are the "same" triangle (you should try and prove this for yourself, it'll be a good practice). This implies that $$\text{Length of }DA \;=\; \text{Length of }DC \;=\; 3.$$ You should be able to determine the radius of the circle with that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but How do I know they are congruent? All I have is DD' being a common side and DD'A = DD'C, which I don't think is enough to prove congruency.

Comment: Both triangles DAD' and DCD' share the same "verticle" side DD'. As for their "horizontal" sides AD' and CD' respectively, using Similar Triangles, you can show that they are both half the length of CA (consider the triangles DAD' and MAC). Then, by Pythagoras's Theorem, they should have the same hypothenuse.